# How can you only filter by the specific object clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to filter an array of tweets inside objects, so that whenever a button is clicked, only the clicked tweet appears.[image]

So this is the site with the tweets and I want that whenever the comment button is clicked, only the title of the specific tweet clicked appears.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './answerform.css'
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import axios from 'axios'

function Answerform() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const modalChange = () => {
    setModal(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/tweets')
      .then(res => setPosts(res.data))
  }, [])

console.log(posts)

    return (
      <div className="tweetform__answer__main">
        <div className="tweetform__modal">
            <form>
            <div className="tweetform__crossicon">
            {posts.filter(post => post.tweets === post.tweets).map(filteredName => (
              <div>
                {filteredName.tweets}
              </div>
            ))}
              <ClearIcon onClick={modalChange} className="tweetform__crossitem"/>
            </div>
              <p>hey</p>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Answerform
```

But with this all the tweets get rendered and not just the one clicked.

This is the array of tweets:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
posts.filter(post => post.tweets === post.tweets)
```

will return the posts array. Nothing is getting filtered in this as `post.tweets === post.tweets` is always true.

You need to compare `post.tweets === clickedPost.tweets` where clickedPost is the post the user clicked on.